# snowsql PUT command

Tags: macos, terminal, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, put

I'm trying to load `user.csv` file through `snowsql` Terminal on Mac and I get this error, and I know there is nothing wrong with the csv file

```
CBILONG#COMPUTE_WH@REVIEWS.PUBLIC>put file:///Macintosh HD\Users\Documents\users.csv @~/staged;
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:                                          
parse error line 1 at position 25 near '85'.
parse error line 1 at position 31 near '68'.
parse error line 1 at position 41 near '117'.
syntax error line 1 at position 42 unexpected 'sers'.
syntax error line 1 at position 46 unexpected '.'.
syntax error line 1 at position 51 unexpected '@~/staged'.
```

Comment: Is there actually a space between "users" and "csv" or is that a typo?

Comment: No there is no space

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? There is definitely a space in the command you have put in your question above and it is in the position that most of the error messages say there is a problem. There is also a space in your filepath (Macintosh HD) so you will need to put single quotes round the filepath: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html#required-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is simply slash vs backslash issue and you don't need Macintosh HD in your path

Try

```
CBILONG#COMPUTE_WH@REVIEWS.PUBLIC>put file:///Users/Documents/users.csv @~/staged;
```

Comment: I tried that and it says the file doesn't exist CBILONG#COMPUTE_WH@REVIEWS.PUBLIC>put file:///Users/Documents/users.csv @~/staged;
253006 (n/a): File doesn't exist: ['/Users/Documents/users.csv']

Comment: Could it be that I might not have a User stage area or is this a default stage in snowflake?

Comment: Make sure you can see the file in finder or in terminal. I think your path is not correct. Usually between "Users" and "Documents" there is another directory with username, might be "cbilon" in your case. Also check the case for the path, since it's case sensitive.

Comment: Your command uses User stage, which exists for each user.

Comment: yea I definitely needed to add the directory between user and documents

Comment: CBILONG#COMPUTE_WH@REVIEWS.PUBLIC>put file:///Users/real/Documents/users.csv @~/staged;
users.csv_c.gz(26.80MB): [##########] 100.00% Done (21.881s, 1.22MB/s).